# java download image directly to specified area

Tags: java, download, inputstream

I already tried to download the image like this:

```
File file4 = new File("C:\\Users\\" + user + "\\AppData\\Roaming"
                + "\\.MINECRAFT2D\\Recources\\"
                + "tileset_texture_new_now.png");
try {
    Image image = null;
    URL url = new URL("http://www.mediafire.com/view/"
                    + "htgmcgtg7yo5swy/tileset_texture_new_now.png");
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int n = 0;
    while (-1 != (n = in.read(buf))) {
         out.write(buf, 0, n);
    }
    out.close();
    in.close();
    byte[] response = out.toByteArray();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file4);
    fos.write(response);
    fos.close();
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

but it leaves an un-viewable image in the location. The image will say: "Photo Gallery can't open this photo or video. The file may be unsupported, damaged or corrupted." Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
byte[] response = out.toByteArray();
```

Close the stream once you made the byte array

```
 while (-1 != (n = in.read(buf))) {
     out.write(buf, 0, n);
}
byte[] response = out.toByteArray();
out.close();
in.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your url is pointing to 'http://www.mediafire.com/view/htgmcgtg7yo5swy/tileset_texture_new_now.png'. It does not resolve to an image/png. I believe that this is the reason of the corrupted image.

Take a look at FileUtils.copyURLToFile(URL, File), from [Apache IO Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/). It might help you downloading files.

Comment: OHHH I just realized, that was the viewing url, not the "download" url. It's working now though. Thanks!